# JQuery Mobile swipe to navigate as single page style

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to JQuery Mobile. Currently trying to use JQM in an ASP.NET MVC project. I am following [this tutorial](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/transitions/swipe-page/) found on JQM official site. But it uses multiple html pages.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-prev="page1" data-next="page3">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `data-next="page3"` is used to show page3.html. My question-  is **page3.html** being loaded by ajax while viewing **page2.html** ?. If I would like to use all the pages in a single html file by using *JQM Page*, how should i proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data-next and data-prev are just arbitrary HTML5 data attributes used in the example to store the url of the next and previous pages. For internal pages you could set them to "#page2", "#page3", etc.  So for 3 pages you might set it up like this:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-prev="" data-next="#page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
         <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        I am page 1
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-prev="#page1" data-next="#page3">
    <div data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
         <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        I am page 2
    </div>
</div>

<div id="page3" data-role="page" data-prev="#page2" data-next="">
    <div data-role="header" data-position='fixed'>
         <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        I am page 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you just update the example's javascript to use the internal url without adding the ".html" to it:

```
function navnext( next ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", next, {
        transition: "slide"
    });
}
function navprev( prev ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prev, {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
    });
}


$( document ).one( "pagecreate", "#page1", function() {
    // Handler for navigating to the next page
    // Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
        // attribute in the original markup.
        var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );
        if ( next ) {
            navnext( next );
        }
    });
    // The same for the navigating to the previous page
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
        if (prev) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });
});
```

jQM uses the **[jqmData()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jqmData/)** function to get and set data attributes.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L2GTD/1/)**